# stop column data from disappearing on web interface when making modifications

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a paper ordering system where a user can search and select a desired paper using a web interface. The user carries out a search by first selecting a supplier using the drop down list `supplier` and then using the search box `paper search` which uses Jquery autocomplete to display the `Product_code`, `description`, `price`, `per`, `pack_qty`pulled out from a database. The user then enters the quantity required and the subtotal and total is calculated dynamically. The user then finally submits their order.

[image]

**Issue:**
The issue I am having, is that when the user tries to modify their existing order, the data is not logged properly and the following data disappears from the web interface: `Product_code`,`price`,`per`,`pack_qty`,`quantity`,`subtotal`,`total`. I have no idea as to why that happens?

[image]

**Code**

```
$(function() {
window.globalVar = 0;

// Skip the filled description boxes
/**for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    if($('#description_'+window.globalVar).val() != "")
    {
        window.globalVar++;
    }
}**/


// Write the paper description and price for the selected paper
function log( message ) {
    var values = message.split('|');
    $('#product_code_'+window.globalVar).val(values[0]);
    $('#description_'+window.globalVar).val(values[1]);
    $('#priceper_'+window.globalVar).val(values[2]);
$('#per_pack_'+window.globalVar).val(values[3]);
$('#pack_qty_'+window.globalVar).val(values[4]);
    //window.globalVar++;
    console.log(window.globalVar);
}


// Search the Paper db
$( "#supplier_search" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://mpc.vario/mis_pp/common/pp_json",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 25,
        name_startsWith: request.term,
        supplier: $('#supplier').val()
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
          return {
            label: item.name,
            value: item.Product_Code + '|' + item.name + '|' + item.value + '|' + item.pack + '|' + item.Pack_qty
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
event.preventDefault();
    log( ui.item.value );
    $(this).val('');
    return false;
  },
  open: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-stop" );
  },
  close: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
  }
});
});
```

Comment: your question is not clear, it is very hard to predict say answer...

Comment: please enter your souce code so we can find out how you store your column data in webpage

Comment: @Ata please find code added above

Answer (score 0):

As you can see description not changes after edit, Also I do not know which one is supplier_search , but as you can see on log() function do not modify description, it means that your problem in based on log or the value that passed to log, please check console.log(message); in log function

Also I do not know why your join item in array and split them again as you can directly pass them

Comment: supplier_search is the drop down list "supplier". I have just checked console and i get an error that says "Uncaught referenceError: val is not defined"? What do you mean by i can directly pass them?

Comment: please update your source code with exact console.log(message) and the value it return, I can not see any val on your source code